# IntelliJ VCS ui problem how can i fix it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I had this commit dialog problem ,it's not readable have can i fix it ??

[image: vcs view]

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail than just ”I had this UI problem.”  What exactly is wrong?  What do you want to see instead?  Edit your question and include the code for the UI (as text, not as an image);  we can’t make suggestions for something we haven’t seen.

Comment: @VGR As I understand it, the OP doesn't have a problem with their code but with IntelliJ's commit dialog.

Comment: Occurs the problem always? I mean, is not something that closing and opening IntelliJ would solve :-) , or? JetBrains IDEs are quite stable, such errors are rare.

Comment: yes, always. closing doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Will it make any difference if you switch theme to Light?

Answer (score 1):

It can be a known issue, please see here:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228312